# Geoexplorer Class Diagram

Tags: geoexplorer, boundless-suite

Does anyone know where I could find a class diagram for the different modules of geoexplorer (geoext and gxp)?

Answer (score 1):

I spoke with a developer on the opengeo suite project and they said that there was not currently an existing diagram.  I did some research and tried to implement js/uml.  Ultimately I've decided that there isn't a great existing, free option to generate javascript uml from source code.

I posted my experiences with js/uml in the question section of the following thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664842/jsdoc-uml-diagram

I just ended up sketching my own diagram.

Answer (score 0):

You could eventually generate a class diagram from the opengeosuite (geexplorer, GeoExt, gxp)?